# ZF & ckeditor. Icons are not loading. Got empty blocks instead of office-buttons

Tags: php, zend-framework, ckeditor

My directory root is "Public" as default in ZF.

The default ZF htaccess also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So editror works but without any icons. I see editor blocks, seems styles work too.

Why icons are not loading?

It stored in /public/js/editor/ckeditor.js.

Here my init code, its from example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if ( window.CKEDITOR )
        {
                (function()
                {
                        var showCompatibilityMsg = function()
                        {
                                var env = CKEDITOR.env;

                                var html = '<p><strong>Your browser is not compatible with CKEditor.</strong>';

                                var browsers =
                                {
                                        gecko : 'Firefox 2.0',
                                        ie : 'Internet Explorer 6.0',
                                        opera : 'Opera 9.5',
                                        webkit : 'Safari 3.0'
                                };

                                var alsoBrowsers = '';

                                for ( var key in env )
                                {
                                        if ( browsers[ key ] )
                                        {
                                                if ( env[key] )
                                                        html += ' CKEditor is compatible with ' + browsers[ key ] + ' or higher.';
                                                else
                                                        alsoBrowsers += browsers[ key ] + '+, ';
                                        }
                                }

                                alsoBrowsers = alsoBrowsers.replace( /\+,([^,]+), $/, '+ and $1' );

                                html += ' It is also compatible with ' + alsoBrowsers + '.';

                                html += '</p><p>With non compatible browsers, you should still be able to see and edit the contents (HTML) in a plain text field.</p>';

                                var alertsEl = document.getElementById( 'alerts' );
                                alertsEl && ( alertsEl.innerHTML = html );
                        };

                        var onload = function()
                        {
                                // Show a friendly compatibility message as soon as the page is loaded,
                                // for those browsers that are not compatible with CKEditor.
                                if ( !CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible )
                                        showCompatibilityMsg();
                        };

                        // Register the onload listener.
                        if ( window.addEventListener )
                                window.addEventListener( 'load', onload, false );
                        else if ( window.attachEvent )
                                window.attachEvent( 'onload', onload );
                })();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Needs more information. Where have you placed the CKEditor files? How are you invoking the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, I found the URL to the icons was ckeditor/plugins/icons.png when I navigated to that image director I got an error "The image cannot be displayed, because it contains errors"

I checked locally it worked.

For me the issues was in my FTP application I had changed the default file transfer mode from auto - to be ASCII. So it was uploading the png as though it was a text file instead of a Binary. Once I changed the transfer mode back to "Auto" everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using FireBug (or similar tool) to check why the images aren't loading. If you look under the 'net' panel you can see weather the icons 404 (not found) or 403 (permissions).

Comment: In example firebug gave me some images. But if I testing my application I'm getting background-image:none; at the same place(